# Explaining how exactly Machine learning determine the result

Tags: machine-learning

Is it possible to somehow reverse the process or based on the model explain how ML model predicted the result?

Example: A bank uses ML for determining the interest rate of a loan for each person. How can I identify based on what data the ML decided the interest rate? For example the ML might discriminate someone (based on wrong data used in training), is there a way to find the problem, find how exactly the ML decided in each case?

Comment: Yes, that is the whole field of explainable AI/ML

Answer (score 0):

This depends on the ML model you are using. Some models tend to be more complicated than others to understand.
The easiest rule-based model that explains the selection rules is a decision tree. You can use Weka for example to create such a tree and later view the branches that lead to each decision.